# Multinomial Coefficients

Tags: statistics

Coach Cramer has 15 basketball players. 4 centers, 5 forwards, and 6 guards. She starts one center, two guards, and two forwards. How many different groups of bench-warmers are possible?

The answer is 600, which can be obtained from
{4 \choose 3}{5 \choose 3}{6 \choose 4} = 600

to do this with the multinomial coefficient I would think I'd take 
15!/(5!3!3!4!)

the 5 is for the # of starters, one 3 for centers and one for forwards and the 4 for guards, but at gives 12,612,600 as the answer. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I do not think there is a natural approach through a multinomial coefficient.

Comment: "the 5 is for the # of starters...etc"  doesn't really say anything about the question. There's no logical implications stated.  And 15!/5!3!3!4! is divisible by 7 so it's not 600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the number of ways to pick $m$ items out of $n$ possible is
$$\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$

So you have to calculate 
$$\frac{4!}{3!1!}*\frac{5!}{2!3!}*\frac{6!}{4!2!} = 600$$